# error: no matching function for call to 'CustomerData::CustomerData()'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stdmap

This is my CreateCustomer method:

```
CustomerData Database::createCustomer(std::string const& name) {
    CustomerData data(customersDb.size()+1, name);
    customersDb[data.number()] = data;
//    customersDb.insert(std::pair<uint, CustomerData>(data.number(), data));
    return data;
}
```

Constructor of class CustomerData:

```
CustomerData::CustomerData(uint number, std::string const& name) {
    m_number = number;
    m_name = name;
}
```

Incorrect line is this one:

```
customersDb[data.number()] = data;
```

Thing is, the next line works. I can't figure it out and can't use insert because accessing element with [] brackets doesn't work either.

I've tried even creating copy constructor but with no effect:

```
CustomerData::CustomerData(CustomerData &data) {
    m_number = data.number();
    m_name = data.name();
}
```

These are the errors:

```
Database.cpp:5: instantiated from here
stl_map.h:450: error: no matching function for call to 'CustomerData::CustomerData()'
CustomerData.h:18: candidates are: CustomerData::CustomerData(CustomerData&)
CustomerData.h:17: note: CustomerData::CustomerData(uint, const std::string&)
```

I use Mingw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator[]` with the standard map template default-constructs an element with the given key if none already exists.

Your element type has no default constructor, so this cannot happen.

You'll have to use `.insert` instead.

```
customersDb.insert(make_pair(data.number(), data));
```

> I can't figure it out and can't use insert because accessing element with [] brackets doesn't work either.

To modify an existing element, retrieve an iterator with `.find`, dereference and do your thing.

```
yourMapType::iterator it = customersDb.find(data.number());
if (it != customersDb.end())
   *it = data;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody. I've chosen your answer because it solves my other problem too, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `operator[]` actually first default constructs the value, and then assigns to it.

---

You can either provide a default constructor, or use this call:

```
customersDb.insert( std::map< uint, CustomerData >::value_type (data.number(), data) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a default constructor for your `CustomerData` class.

```
CustomerData::CustomerData()
{
}
```

Or you implement a code in such a way that it only calls the constructor which you have provided for your class. It is needed by `[]` to default construct an element.

First one looks a better option.

**Reason for error:**

When you provide any constructor for your own class, the compiler does not generate the default no argument constructor and your code needs one and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error, it's in there :)

```
stl_map.h:450: error: no matching function for call to 'CustomerData::CustomerData()'
```

It looks like the compiler thinks you're not actually passing any information to the function.

It does recognize these two alternatives :

```
CustomerData.h:18: candidates are: CustomerData::CustomerData(CustomerData&)
CustomerData.h:17: note: CustomerData::CustomerData(uint, const std::string&)
```

But both take arguments, which you're not passing.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to call the constructor on your CustomerData class, but it doesn't exist. I'm pretty sure this is something to do with how the standard map works internally. The value of the map must have a default constructor. This would normally be generated by the compiler, but as you have already provided another constructor it was not generated.

Comment: No it's not. It's trying to call the _default_ constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure there is default (blank) constructor so the type can be constructed without args.

```
myclass(); //implement somewhere
```

you can also provide default args

```
myclass(const std::string& value="hello"); //implement somewhere
```

in  C++11 you can do this

```
myclass()=default; //implementation will be generated
```